# Can a set of data have multiple medians?

Tags: statistics, means, median

I'm looking at a probability distribution where the cumulative probability distribution for a random variable $X_2$ is exactly 0.5. Does this mean that the distribution has multiple medians?

Comment: there can be multiple medians, e.g. if $X_2$ has the values $0$ or $1$

Comment: What does that mean intuitively? Doesn't median divide the distribution equally? Would having multiple medians mean that we are redefining our sample?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you define as "median". What would you consider the median of $\{0,2\}$ to be? For a real-valued random variable, if the cumulative density function is constant at $0.5$ over an open interval, then it means that the possible values jump across a gap. It is reasonable to define the median as the midpoint of the gap, in which case there will always only be one median if any. For discrete distributions, you may want to consider the median of $\{0,2\}$ to be both $0$ and $2$, but this would not extend naturally to non-discrete distributions, because what would the median of $X$ be where $X$ takes a value in $[0,1)$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and takes a value in $(2,3]$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Thanks! That does make a lot of sense. One question though, does that mean there would always be a median in a discrete frequency distribution?

Comment: @dexter: $\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}$For any real random variable (discrete or not), it has a cumulative distribution function $F$ that is increasing, left-continuous, and has limits $0$ and $1$ towards $-\infty$ and $\infty$ respectively. Thus there must be reals $a = \inf( \{ x : x \in \rr \land F(x) \ge \frac{1}{2} \} )$ and $b = \sup( \{ x : x \in \rr \land F(x) \le \frac{1}{2} \} )$. We can define median to be $\frac{a+b}{2}$.